# Jakarta Mail create attachment without datahandler

Tags: groovy, jakarta-mail, apache-nifi

I am trying to attach data coming from an `InputStream` as a `MimeBodyPart` to be sent as an email attachment. I understand how this can be done using a `DataSource` and `DataHandler` object, however that involves writing the data to memory. As this code is to be used on a large dataset on a server that does not scale well and i am looking to keep the data just in the inputStream object directly to the the `MimeBodyPart`

As this code is to be used on a large dataset on a server that does not scale well and i am looking to keep the data just in the `InputStream` object directly to the the `MimeBodyPart`